# hadoop is oltp or olap software and does it work on real time? and what for it is used does it replaces any existing system?

Tags: hadoop

I can understand that it splits the task to several machines parallely to increase the performance and combines their outcomes to obtain final outcome using map reduce algorithm of google's but i cann't understand in which way other than that it replaces the tradition rdms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hadoop at the core is just HDFS ( a distributed file system) and MapReduce ( a parallel processing computation framework). Today it grew to an eco-system which can do a lot. There probably are not a lot of OLTP workloads in Hadoop but for sure there are OLAP workloads. Many people are offloading DW/BI (DataWarehouse and Business Intelligence) workloads to Hadoop. Real-time streaming and processing is a prominent use case (using storm etc....). When probably it is built it is not meant to replace any system but solve problems that are of internet scale where there aren't many established systems/patterns at that moment. But today with its large ecosystem and capabilities it can be used (as replacement) for DW, NoSQL, streaming, messaging, Machine Learning, SQL etc..... (the list goes on)